# Hiding and showing sidebar div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a site [here](http://billischill.ddns.net) and I want to hide and show the sidebar with a button in the header but it is not working. Here is what I have tried:

```
<div id="B">
    <button>toggle</button>
</div>
```

```js
$('button').toggle(function() {
    $('#sidebarright').animate({ left: 0 })
}, function() {
    $('#sidebarright').animate({ left: 200 })
})
```

Nothing happens. Could you help me find out the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toggle()` functionality you're trying to use has now been deprecated and removed from the latest versions of jQuery. To replicate it you can use the `click()` event with a simple ternary expression. Try this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var $el = $('#sidebarright');
    $el.animate({
        left: parseInt($el.css('left'), 0) == 0 ? 200 : 0
    });
});
```

Also note that the page you link to on your website does not contain a reference to jQuery. Here's how you should do that, along with a full implementation of the above code:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('button').toggle(function() {
                var $el = $('#sidebarright');
                $el.animate({
                    left: parseInt($el.css('left'), 0) == 0 ? 200 : 0
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Also note that you can simplify this by using CSS transitions only and toggling a class:

```css
#sidebarright {
    /* UI styling rules here */
    left: 0;
    transition: left 0.5s
}
#sidebarright.open {
    left: 200;
}
```

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#sidebarright').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: Well it doesn't work right I got it to do something at least but it's messed up please not that my sidebar is on the right can you please help.             I am using your second method

Comment: Sir I did some tweaking and it works now but it automatically fires off as soon as I open the page

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery Script but you have not attached jQuery file in header.
Please add jQuery File in header.

Download it from http://www.jquery.com

Comment: This is already said in existing accepted answer. Your answer gives no value ad or alternative solution.